# Unexpected behavior when converting double precision to text in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, formatting, greenplum

*Came across this weird behavior today..*

```
select                date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE);
2017
select        to_char(date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE),'9999');
" 2017"
select length(to_char(date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE),'9999'));
5
```

Of course I can directly use `to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY')`, but just curious why double precision numbers get a blank space in the beginning when converted into text. *Thank you!*

---

Notes:

- [Data Type Formatting Functions (PostgreSQL 8.2.xx)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html)
- Server version: PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.3.10.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is documented (see the [examples table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-EXAMPLES-TABLE)).  It's leaving space for a `-` sign for negative values.

It seems that you can avoid this with the `FM` prefix, i.e. `'FM9999'`.

Comment: Ah I didn't catch that during my first pass. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @Kent They also wrote that: `If no explicit provision is made for a sign in to_char()'s pattern, one column will be reserved for the sign, and it will be anchored to (appear just left of) the number. If S appears just left of some 9's, it will likewise be anchored to the number.`

Comment: @krokodilko - Thanks! I see that's in the latest v10 docs, and missing in mine. It's explained well